# How do i use Jquery menu in drupal

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules

I have the jquery menu module installed, enabled and set to work on the primary links in the configuration. I put

```
<?php echo $primary_links; ?>
```

into my page.tpl.php file but it does not show the jquery menu functionality. I have also tried putting the primary links into a region using the blocks but that does not work either.. i have been googling this for hours and not found any documentation or examples anywhere but i know this is a well used drupal module. What am i doing wrong? i am having a blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which jquery menu module are you trying to use? There are many ways to create dynamic flyout menus using jquery and drupal, and a number of drupal modules that don't use jquery.

I've found that [nice menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) works well for a number of situation, and is usually very easy to implement, requiring little or no coding.